# How to ignore whitespace in python

Tags: python, regex, removing-whitespace

I am trying to check for a string,if it's present I don't want to write to a file but the string has whitespacce between them at different position and that is making it difficult to capture.

Sample text:

```
this is test (enclosed ("further enclosed...
Line to be printed:1
this is test(enclosed ("further enclosed...
Line to be interpreted 
this is test(enclosed("further enclosed...
this is test (enclosed("further enclosed...
```

Expected Output

```
Line to be printed:1
Line to be printed:2
```

I tried the below code but it's not working :

```
for word in words:
    if 'this is test .*(enclosed .*(\"' not in word :
        fw.write (word)
```

I am writing it to a file.

Can someone help me with how to achieve the expected output? Let me know if you need further details.Also, I don't want to use something like

```
if 'this is test (enclosed (\"' not in word or 'this is test(enclosed(\"' not in word :
```

Comment: `enlclosed` or `enclosed` ?

Comment: and `not in` won't look for regexes. You have to use the regex package explicitly.

Comment: two ways to solve the problem:1) put optional spaces everywhere in the pattern (Neos07 approach) or 2) normalize the line (with `re.sub`) before testing it with a more simple pattern (with `re.match`). I let you choose the most appropriate approach.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre enclosed (ignore the typo)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte and _use the regex package_ :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: refresh, you are right.

Comment: @Saurabh are you aware that you're _not_ using the `re` package so `.*` and such are treated as _normal_ strings?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: it's the first time I see this kind of mistake, however many languages don't need a special package/module to use regex.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have "import re"  statement in my code. So it should work right? or is there anything else also that I should use ?

Comment: yeah: use `re.search` not `in`. Importing `re` doesn't turn substring search into regex search.

Comment: @Saurabh: the `import` statement doesn't add capabilities to the language but makes available methods from the imported module. Look at the re module manual page to see which new methods are available and how to use them.

Comment: Oh okay. Got it. Thanks guys. Using re.search worked.

Answer (score -2):

I think the issue isn't the whitespace, but you didn't escape the parentheses.
For whitespace, you can use \s instead of .
so your regex will be:

```
this is test\s*\(enclosed\s*\("
```

Comment: except that OP isn't using regex _at all_

Comment: but he used the regex tag in his question.

Comment: @Neos07 : I tried your solution. Unfortunately. It didn't work